# Check if list consists of integers alone

Tags: python

I have a program which

- reverses the order of a list if the list consists of integers alone
- converts the list items to uppercase if the list contains words only
- returns the same list if the list members don’t satisfy either of these two criteria

I have written it though I want the program to loop through the list, if the value of type `int` -append and when next value of type string display original list and end loop

I think that my code my code doesn't do it well:

```
def is_int(val):
    if type(val) == int:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def is_string(val):
      if type(val) == str:
         return True
      else:
         return False

def is_float(val):
    if type(val) == float:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def invert(val):
    k = len(val)

    for i in range(k//2):
        a = val[i]
        val[i] = val[k-1]
        val[k-1] = a

    print(val)


lis = ["a","c",2,7]
lim = []
tart = 1
for x in lis:
    if is_int(x) == True and is_int(lis[tart:]) == True:
        lim.append(x)
        tart += 1
    elif is_string(x) == True and is_string(lis[tart:]) == True :
        x = x.upper()
        lim.append(x)
        tart += 1
    else:
        print(lis)
        break


invert(lim)
```

Comment: At which point is it failing? Are you subroutines working as you expect them to?

Comment: @Loebl how to make sure it makes a check whether the list only contains integers and then the item is appended. if the list contains a mixture, move on to the else part and print out the original list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use this -

```
all(isinstance(i, int) for i in lis)
```

This will give you `True` if all the elements of list are integer, then you can modify your code to test against strings and integers

```
if all(isinstance(i, int) for i in lis):
    return list(reversed(lis)) # return reversed list
elif all(isinstance(i, str) for i in lis):
    return [i.upper() for i in lis] # change to uppercase and return the list
return lis # return list as is
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following instead:

```
if all(isinstance(i, int) for i in lis):
    lim = lis[::-1]
elif all(isinstance(i, str) for i in lis):
    lim = [i.upper() for i in lis]
```